# best way to send an xml file to an url via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml, post, xmlhttprequest

I am dynamically creating xml files from data sourced from mysql database. I need to send (POST) the xml file to a specified URL on another server. I have spent hours reading about several methods but cannot find a simple and succinct script example to do this. Assuming the xml file is example.xml and the recipient url is https://destination.co.uk/destination; could anyone help with a simple php or javascript for doing this please. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps there is no *simple* method. Why not try ones you have found first?

Comment: I would be interested in the community's expert view on what constitutes the most straight forward way of achieving this. Hence the reason for asking the community.

Comment: StackOverflow questions are meant to be a bit more specific, not opinion-based or too broad. Those types of questions would be considered off-topic and are subject closure. Maybe take a look through the asking question area and see if maybe this falls under that category. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. As for which might be the most straightforward is really a matter of opinion.

Have you checked out GuzzleHttp? That might be one of the most simplest tools you could use to accomplish what your asking.

I personally would just use curl.